# How to remove hardlink to /home created by timeshift?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, directory, backup, hard-link

After installing timeshift on Kali Linux, the same device/drive with a different name/path was created as seen in the system monitor under the `File Systems` tab:
[image]

Even after uninstalling timeshift, the created drive is present.
Since it is exactly the same as the `/dev/sda4` drive as seen in the image above, I am doubtful if the command `sudo rm -rf /run/timeshift` will only delete the created copy of `/home` and not the entire `/home` itself.

**Main Question-** I want to remove that drive (or some kind of a link, possibly) created by timeshift.

**Research till now:**
After learning about hard links and soft links, I guess that's a hard link timeshift has created. But I also learned that hard links are not created for directories.

This is what made me ask this question here.

Comment: Directories cannot be hardlinked. The disk is mounted in two places. Try `umount /run/timeshift/backup`

Comment: If the backup is deleted from `/timeshift` the drive gets unmounted.